# how to fetch the largest value of a given data type in c?

Tags: c

I am new to C.

for.eg say `int` has a largest value of 32767(but this value can be different for other system), my question is how to obtain these value for any datatype using a C program or function.

for `int` I was trying this approach, but it returns `-1`

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(void){

unsigned int x=1;
unsigned long count=0;

for(x=1;;x++){

    if(x==0){break;}
    count++; 

    }

printf("%ld",count);

}
```

Comment: Its `UINT_MAX` and `ULONG_MAX` you are after ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The header `limits.h` has a constant `UINT_MAX`, which is the value you want.

The reason you saw `-1` is just that `%ld` is the wrong printf format for `unsigned long`. Use `%lu`.

C isn't really geared for generic programming, but the most recent standard C11 does provide macros that do different things according to the type of the argument ("type-generic expressions").

I've never used them, but I expect you could write a macro `NUMERIC_LIMITS_MAX` to hide the mapping `int -> INT_MAX`, `unsigned char -> UCHAR_MAX`, etc. The resulting code would not (yet) be very portable, since there aren't many partial implementations of C11, let alone complete ones.

That said, for unsigned types you can always get the max value as `(unsigned long)(-1)` and so on. The signed types are a bit awkward, because the standard gives implementations freedom to do a lot of strange things. In practice, `INT_MAX` is equal to `(((unsigned int)(-1)) / 2) + 1`. In theory, `int` is allowed to have more padding bits than `unsigned int`, in which case `INT_MAX` is smaller.

Comment: but what if I am on a 64-bit system, then these values might be wrong for that system, because the values in this header are all constants.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: the values in the header are always correct for the C implementation you are using. If you have a 64-bit implementation and I have a 32-bit implementation, then the contents of your `limits.h` are not the same as mine. Likewise, if you're on a 64-bit system but compiling/running a 32-bit executable, you'll see different values for some limits than if you're compiling for 64-bit.

Comment: ah! you're right using `%lu`, now my program and UINT_MAX are returning same value.

Answer (score 6):

`limits.h` defines a few values that represent the limits (or bounds) of types. In your case, `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` would be a portable way to find out the minimum and maximum values an `int` can hold.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/limits.h

Comment: but what if I am on a 64-bit system, then these values might  be wrong for that system, because the values in this header are all constants.

Answer (score 3):

Check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/climits/). Generally when you have a question regarding C or C++ try to first look it up at this site, it's a great reference.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [`#include <limits.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html)

Answer (score 0):

Solution to get the max of int in running time:

```
int main ( )
{
    unsigned int y = (unsigned int)(~0)>>1;
    printf ("max of int is %u\r\n",y);
    return 1;
}
```

**explaination:**

`y = ~0` set y with the opposite in binary of 0. If our system is 32 bits so 0 will be represent in binary with (0000...0)(32) and its opposite in binary is (1111...1)(32).

`y>>1` shift the y with 1 bit so the value of y will be (0111..1)(31) which is the max of int

Comment: If we printf -1 as hexadeciaml printf ("%X\n",-1) it will show 0xFFFFFFFF. and I m not sur that all architecture represent -1 as 0XFFF... I updated the code with another solution which works for all architectures

Comment: y = ~0  is the size of unsigned int. If we devide y per 2 we will get the size of int. y/2 is the same of y>>1

Answer (score 0):

Just print -1

```
#include "stdint.h"

printf("Byte :%u, Short :%hu,  Int :%u, Long Long :%llu\n",
             (uint8_t)-1, (uint16_t)-1, (uint32_t)-1, (uint64_t)-1);
```

The Output is:

> Byte :255, Short :65535,  Int :4294967295, Long Long
>   :18446744073709551615

I am on linux...

Comment: Yes it does, But For signed data types i guess following should work

`printf("Byte :%u, Short :%hu,  Int :%u, Long Long :%llu\n", ((uint8_t)-1)/2, ((uint16_t)-1)/2, ((uint32_t)-1)/2, ((uint64_t)-1)/2);`